# What kind of adjustments are "Brightness" and "Contrast"?

Tags: single-word-requests, collective-nouns

I have "Brightness" and "Contrast" adjustments on my monitor. What would be a word that those could be grouped into? "Picture Adjustments" perhaps?

I was hoping for something more specific, because moving the position and such could also be considered a "Picture Adjustment".

Comment: You might call them "viewing-quality adjustments," in contradistinction to "screen positioning adjustments." The relevant [Microsoft page](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/adjust-monitor-brightness-contrast#1TC=windows-7) doesn't use a categorical name for the two variables.

Comment: Your *monitor* probably doesn't allow adjustment of ***resolution***, for example. But in principle is that another one of the video attribute adjustments you want included?

Comment: @FumbleFingers No, I just want a group that describes Brightness and Contrast. I'd like if the group name separated itself from things like resolution and position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Among the 3 big graphics card makers these are generally grouped into the **Color** aggregate. If 3 companies that can hardly agree on anything go with the same group name who am I to object? I think **Color Adjustments** is an accepted grouping.

Pictures bellow (in alphabetical order, less some fanboy kick the bucket):

And AMD seems to have chosen **Display Color Adjustments**:

[image]

Intel uses **Color Enhancement**:

[image]

Nvidia uses **Color Settings**:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've always heard these categorized under picture settings. Things like color warmth, black levels, etc., also get grouped here.

Some could refer to these as display settings, too, but generally display settings are more commonly things like resolution. A rule of thumb could be -- if it affects the visual look of the image itself (color, contrast), it's a picture setting. If it's instead more closely related to matching the picture to the display in a technical sense (resolution, aspect ratio), it's a display setting. Therefore changes such as bumping the image up or down a couple of pixels to fit your monitor would be a display setting change.

Generally speaking though the categories are not very concretely defined, and in everyday usage, I don't think anyone would get confused by referring to any such setting by either term.

With dials and buttons on the monitor itself, I usually just group them as "monitor settings," since I also have the ability to alter the image through software. Categorizing it as a monitor setting therefore gives more immediate information than either picture or display would.

Comment: Ah, but some manufacturers used *picture* synonymously with *contrast* (and *color* with *saturation*, and *tint* with *hue*). Apparently, [Sony still does](https://us.en.kb.sony.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/41113/~/the-entire-picture-has-a-red,-green,-or-blue-tint.). Thus, *picture* or *picture settings* can be ambiguous, especially to people who tweaked such things in the analog CRT days.